# Error, ever one column in bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

Im try update wallpapers website html and add bootstrap. Well, i have error when i try show all wallpapers in 3 columns. Ever see that in one column, some one can help me?

For more information: I add this codes or structure:

```
<div class="container"> + <div class="row"> + <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
```

I using this theme: https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-3-col-portfolio

This is website: fondos24.com

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the row doesn't have any style. Did you include all files?

You can also solve this problem yourself. Bootstrap uses flex for this example. By adding `display: flex;` to your row element you can solve this.

```
.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This is the same solution Bootstrap gives you.

Comment: Yes, im loading all files with CDN oficial of bootstrap. All files in theme and another like jquery and etc...